# Taking the specific value of a div based on class id

Tags: javascript

In my html page I have a tag with this format:

```
<p class="pclass">Cclass</p>
```

I want to take the value Cclass and add it to a variable. I tried to use this:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("pclass").innerHTML;
```

Is there a different way to do it?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of DOM elements that match your class name. To get the first one, add `[0]` after it, as you would with an Array. You could also do `document.querySelector(".pClass")` which will only return the first one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use an index to get that you want.

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("pclass")[0].innerHTML;
```

This is because this method:

> Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of
>   the given class names.

For further documentation please have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("pclass")[0].innerHTML;
document.write(x);
```

```html
<p class="pclass">Cclass</p>
```

Comment: @blex Thank you very much for spotting my error :) ! I was using a capital C instead of c :(.

Comment: @blex yup, but I didn't spot it first :)